# Ajax - jQuery and Ajax errors/not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, ajax

I am building a webpage that contains a `div` which holds some data retrieved from a MySql database through PHP. This div shows some products and on its left there is a simple nav bar with different categories. What I am attempting to do is that when the user clicks a category of this nav bar, the content of the `div` will change, showing the products of that category all of which are stored in the db. So I tried using Ajax (my first time btw), and I can't seem to make it work. My project structure is something like this:

Parent directory

- php > index.php
- css > index.css
- js > index.js
- img > images here
- ajax> products-ajax.js / products-ajax.php

The index.php file is linked to both index.js AND products-ajax.js
However, I have already tried including the Ajax line of code in both index.js and index.php but I can't make it recieve data back from products-ajax.php
Any help is appreciated.

And here's what my test code looks like:

```js
/* THIS IS THE products-ajax.js */

$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.products-list li').click(function(){

  $.post("products-ajax.php",
               {p: "Product name"},
               success: function(data){alert(data)}
        );
  
 });
});
```

```html
<?php

/* THIS IS THE products-ajax.php */

$p = $_POST['p'];

echo $p;

?>
```

I realized my broswer's debugger says there's a missing parentheses:

```
$('.products-list li').click(function(){
 //The debugger says HERE v should go a parentheses
$.post("products-ajax.php", {p: "Product name"}, success: function(data{alert(data)});

});
```

Comment: What is the error ? What should happen and what is not happening ?

Comment: @RayonDabre This is just a really simple test to see if Ajax would work in my page. The problem is that products-ajax.php should send $p as the `data` parameter in products-ajax.js and then display it as an alert. It doesn't seem to be sending either the request to the php file or the data back from it

Comment: @bhelmet Thanks for reminding me that the browser has a debugger! The debugger says this:
`SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`
Which would be right after the `"products-ajax.php"`, in the javascript file

Comment: Try this: `$.post("products-ajax.php", {p: "Product name"}, function (data) {
    alert(data);
   });` Refer [this](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) for detailed documentation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `$.ajax()` instead of `$.post()`, you could add an error handler which would give you precious information (maybe you can with `$.post()`, but I'm not familiar with this function, which afaik is just a shortcut to `$.ajax()`).
It could be something like :

```
var request = $.ajax({
    url: "products-ajax.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: { p: "Product name" }
});
request.done(function( data ) {
    alert( data );
});
request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
    alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
});
```

Edit: and prefer `console.log()` rather than `alert()` for debugging. Especially with asynchronous interactions, `alert()` sometimes leads to surprises...

Comment: I think you solved my problem! Didn't use `$.ajax though` . My debugger said there was a missing parentheses
 $.post("products-ajax.php", /*Here missing parentheses*/ {p: "Product name"}, success: function(data{alert(data)});

So I just made the request variable like this `var request = $.post("products-ajax.php")` and then added the .done() and .fail() functions and it worked. Thanks bro!

Comment: here you had a syntax problem in js, which you can debug in the browser. But in some cases, your js is correct and still you have unexpected results, so it's better to handle fails too (can be a 404-Not found if typo in url, a timeout, whatsoever...)